# How to define a Array of Array Model scheme in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to store an array like below in MongoDB:

```
[
  [ '6332fad5bf088ffa638bf4c0', 
     '[{"today":"2022-10-11"}, {"index":"633e94ae86bc0a6247ea325b"},10]
  ],
  [
    '633e94ae86bc0a6247ea325b',
    '[{"today":"2022-10-11"},{"index":"633e94ae86bc0a6247ea325b"},10]'
  ],
]
```

I also defined it as an Array in Model Scheme

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserWorkoutHistory = {
  workout: Array,

};

const UserWorkoutScheme = mongoose.model(
  'UserWorkoutHistory',
  UserWorkoutHistory
);

module.exports = UserWorkoutScheme;
```

Although I got the right data in post route, the only thing I got is an [] stored in MongoDB. Any solutions are welcomed

Comment: Hello. This is the area of Stack Overflow for the Scheme / Lisp language. Have you posted in the correct area?

Comment: Your inner array elements are of different types, is that what you need?